# How to pass JSON object from Node JS middleware to .ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, datatables, ejs

I'm working with a NodeJS Express app with an EJS engine.

How can I pass a json object to my table.ejs file to be displayed in a table?

This is how I'm currently trying to do it. (I added some dummy JSON data into this table.ejs script and the table populated, so I know that portion works.)

This is a snippet of the middleware function that I have. I'm receiving data in from a Python API.

app.js

```
app.post('/process', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/receive', jsonData)
    .then(response => {

      const jsonData_response = response.data;
      res.render("table", { jsonData_res: jsonData_res });
      //console.log(jsonData_res);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error sending data:', error);
    });
```

I want to pass this json to my table.ejs file to be displayed in a data table.

Here is the snippet of html from my table.ejs

table.ejs

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

                <script>
                   let dataset  = JSON.parse('<%-JSON.stringify(jsonData_res)%>');
                        $('#example').DataTable({
                            data: dataSet,
                            columns: [
                                { title: 'Name' },
                                { title: 'Position' },
                                { title: 'Office' },
                                { title: 'Extn.' },
                                { title: 'Start date' },
                                { title: 'Salary' },
                            ],
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                <div>
                    <table id="example" class="display">

                    </table>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this technique of injecting object as JSON from server, you don't need to `parse` it because it's already a string representing an object.

```js
// server
var obj = {
  hello: "world"
}

// pass to client
var code = ("var obj = " + JSON.stringify(obj))
console.log(code)

// result
var obj = {"hello":"world"}
```

Comment: How would you pass that to the table.ejs file tho? I would presume this would be an error?